# redirect http://www.domain.com to https://domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following apache virtualhost:

```
NameVirtualHost  *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /home/www/htdocs/domain.tl/html/>

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tl$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.domain.tl/$1 [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName domain.tl
    ServerAlias www.domain.tl fr.domain.tl en.domain.tl files.domain.tl
    DocumentRoot /home/www/htdocs/domain.tl/html/

    ...

    <Directory /home/www/htdocs/domain.tl/html/>

        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tl$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fr.domain.tl/$1 [L,R=301]

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to redirect the http://www.domain.tl OR http://domain.tl to https://fr.domain.tl

Actually with this virtualhost, the redirection http to https is correct but the sub domain do not change

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tl$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.domain.tl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

to

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)domain.tl$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fr.domain.tl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

so that it also matches "www.domain.tl" and redirects to https in both your virtual hosts:

Comment: @Paul have you cleared your cache? You have a 301 redirect that does that and 301's are permanent (so the browsers cache that forever).